# Outer measure of a null set

Tags: measure-theory, solution-verification

Outer measure of a null set is zero.

proof 1: By definition of outer measure, $m^*(\varnothing)\geq 0.$
Clearly $\varnothing\subseteq (-\frac{1}{n},\frac{1}{n}),\forall n\in \Bbb{N}.$
Therefore, $\varnothing\subseteq\cup_{n=1}^{\infty}(-\frac{1}{n},\frac{1}{n}).$
$m^*(\varnothing)\leq m^*(\cup_{n=1}^{\infty}(-\frac{1}{n},\frac{1}{n}))\leq \sum_{n=1}^\infty m^*(-\frac{1}{n},\frac{1}{n})=\sum_{n=1}^\infty l(-\frac{1}{n},\frac{1}{n})=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{2}{n}, $

which diverges.

Proof 2:  By definition of outer measure, $m^*(\varnothing)\geq 0.$
Clearly $\varnothing\subseteq (-\frac{\epsilon}{2^{n+1}},\frac{\epsilon}{2^{n+1}}),\forall n\in \Bbb{N}$,
Therefore  $\varnothing\subseteq\cup_{n=1}^\infty(-\frac{\epsilon}{2^{n+1}},\frac{\epsilon}{2^{n+1}}).$
$m^*(\varnothing)= \text{inf}\big\{\sum_{n=1}^\infty l(-\frac{\epsilon}{2^{n+1}},\frac{\epsilon}{2^{n+1}})\big\}\leq\sum_{n=1}^\infty l(-\frac{\epsilon}{2^{n+1}},\frac{\epsilon}{2^{n+1}})=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\epsilon}{2^n}=\epsilon.$

Since $\epsilon >0$ is arbitrary. Hence $m^*(\varnothing)\leq 0$.
Thus $m^*(\varnothing)=0$.

Am I done wrong in *proof1*? For me *proof2* sounds nicer.

If proof2 is correct, then fine. I am interested to know the proof1(only). Can choice of interval $(-\frac{1}{n},\frac{1}{n})$ is fine?

Help me with proof 1!

Comment: The first proof tells you that $0 \leq m^*(\emptyset) \leq +\infty.$ This is a true result, but not a very precise result.

Comment: The first proof shows that the empty set is a subset of the union of countably many open intervals whose lengths have an infinite sum. Since the outer measure is the **infimum** of all such countably many interval length sums, we know from this that the outer measure is at most infinite (which doesn't tell us anything we didn't already know), and for all we know there might be other countable coverings by intervals that have smaller (i.e. less than infinite) interval length sums, and in fact this is the case.

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro Proof1 does not work really good. right!

Comment: As an analogy, suppose you want to find the minimum of $\{\frac{1}{2}, \;\frac{1}{3}, \;5, \;18,\; 0,\; 244,\; \frac{3}{7}, \;2 \}$ (which is $0).$ Your proof 1 is analogous to picking $244$ and saying that this is the minimum. However, by picking $244,$ all we can conclude is that the minimum is at most $244,$ because for any (finite) set $S$ of real numbers, if $x \in S,$ then it follows that $x \leq \min(S).$

Comment: Now I am very confused. Please give a comment on proof1...Am I wrong in proof1?

Comment: *Am I wrong in proof1?* --- Proof 1 only shows that the outer measure of the empty set is between zero and infinity. In proof 1 you give a covering by intervals in which the lengths of the intervals add to infinity. Thus, the *smallest possible sum of lengths of intervals covering the empty set* is known to not be greater than infinity. But we already know this. Thus, proof 1 shows $m^*(\emptyset) \leq +\infty.$ However, proof 1 does not show that $m^*(\emptyset) = 0,$ or even that $m^*(\emptyset) < +\infty.$

Comment: Thank you so much sir! I got it.

Answer (score 0):

Contradiction works best with the empty set. Suppose $\mu(\emptyset)>0$. Then there should be an open interval $(a,b)\subseteq \emptyset$, and that is not true.

Comment: I am not interested in other proof. I have many proofs for the said problem.

Comment: this isn't even a right contradiction proof (which is why what I'm about to say may sound weird). The (outer) measure of empty set being positive does not imply the existence of an interval being contained in the empty set, so there's a jump in your logic. In general positive measure does NOT imply it contains an interval (think of fat cantor sets for example).